# integrate google apps to the build to be installed in /data/app

Tags: android, youtube, rom

i try to make my own rom, and I want add google-apps to the build to be installed in /data/app

this is the steps :

1 - create new folder called "gapps" in vendor/ dir
2- in "gapps" add data/app/Youtube/app/youtube.apk,
3- create android.mk file in "gapps" folder with this content

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := YouTube
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := data/app/YouTube/YouTube.apk
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT_DATA_APPS)
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER := GOLDROM
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

4 - go to the build dir in the android root files build/target/product/core.mk and add YouTube to the PRODUCT_PACKAGES var

5- build, flash, but youtube not found.

plz correct me , if i made any mistak.   :)

Comment: Download the GApps package, remove any google related app from System/App or System/priv-app, Then copy the APKs folders and paste them to data/app, for example data/app/com.google.youtube/youtube.apk .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to add your module to PRODUCT_PACKAGES var

```
rootAndroid/build/target/product/generic_no_telephony.mk
```

and then youtube will work fine in /data as a user app

**but its still a not clean solution.**